# How to return a 'read-only' copy of a vector

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I have a class which has a private attribute vector rectVec;

```
class A {
private:
   vector<Rect> rectVec;
};
```

My question is how can I return a 'read-only' copy of my Vector?
I am thinking of doing this:

```
class A {
public:
  const vect<Rect>& getRectVec() { return rectVect; }
}
```

Is that the right way? 
I am thinking this can guard against the callee modify the vector(add/delete Rect in vector), what about the Rect inside the vector?

Comment: That sounds a bit confused. If you make a copy, why does it matter whether or not it is read-only? And if you want read-only access to the original data, then you're not making a copy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is the right way, although you'll probably want to make the function `const` as well.

```
class A {
public:
  const vect<Rect>& getRectVec() const { return rectVect; }                           
};
```

This makes it so that people can call `getRectVec` using a `const A` object.

Comment: This does not seem to work for a `const vector<unique_ptr<T>>&`. Is there a way to return a read only vector/STL container whose `T*` or `unique_ptr<T>` objects cannot be modified as well as the vector cannot be modified, i. e. a entirely read only vector? The items and the vector itself should be alterable within the holding class of course.

Answer (score 7):

That's the normal way. `const` means "you cannot modify this". It also applies to the elements within the container.

A simple test:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> int_vec;

struct foo
{
    const int_vec& get(void)
    {
        return v;
    }

    int_vec v;
};

int main(void)
{
    foo f;
    f.v.push_back(1);
    f.v.push_back(2);
    f.v.push_back(3);

    f.get()[0] = 2; // nope
}
```

---

`const_cast` could be used to strip the `const` away, but you'd then end up with undefined behavior if you modified a variable through it:

```
int_vec& v = const_cast<int_vec&>(f.get()); // this is okay
v[0] = 0; // but now we've entered undefined behavior
```

Comment: If you must defend against const being cast away, and don't mind the (huge) performance penalty, you can return a copy of the vector. This way the caller can change it in any way they want and not affect the private vector. Simply return by value rather than reference.

Comment: "end up with undefined behavior": Not exactly, because `v` is not declared as const in the first place.

Comment: @Arkadiy: It's already defended by leading to undefined behavior. Nobody should have to say or do anything more; those who wish to entered Undefined Behavior Land can surely perish.

Comment: @GMan as AraK said, it is only UB to cast away const-ness if the pointed-to/referred-to object was declared as const. Casting away constness on a pointer or reference to an object that is not itself const is perfectly well defined, although usually indicative of bad design.

Comment: @AraK @Tyler: Hm, I always thought it was just any `const`, regardless of source. Oh well, I still maintain the "wtf are you doing" approach to disregarding `const_cast` worries.

Comment: Although AraK is right because your function `get` is not declared as const, use of 'const_cast' is a bad design anyway.

Comment: It *can* be bad design.  It can also be required in order to interface with a bad design.

Answer (score 4):

I know its a rather old post but its one of the top google results when searching for "c++ read only vector". Thats why I want to post my approach nevertheless.

If you want the container itself to be const but not its elements you can use an approach similar to this one:

```cpp
template<class Container>
class Enumerable
{
public:
    Enumerable(Container& container) : _container(container) {}

    auto begin() const { return _container.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return _container.end(); }

    const Container& GetContainer() const { return _container; }
    const Container* operator->() const { return &_container; }

private:
    Container& _container;
};
```

With that you can iterate over your container and modify its elements while ensuring the container itself stays the same. You may want to expose more functionality of the container by specializing the class for e.g. vectors by providing an indexing operator.

I'm not entirely sure if its good design to expose a container like that but its definitely a useful pattern for some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way, unless the user casts the constness away using `const_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of returning a reference to your vector, return a new type that wraps the vector (contains a const reference to the vector) and exposes only the functionality you wish to allow the caller to access.  I'm guessing this isn't much since you want to prevent mutability of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

in general this is bad practice. You are exposing your internal implementation to your callers. You are better of either returning a wrapper class instance (mentioned before) or exposing functions that get items or iterators (typedefed to match your implementation)

Comment: The read-only vector doesn't expose anything. The function hides the underlying representation from the caller. The proof is that underlying representation could vary, if necessary, at some point in the future. As long as the public interface doesn't change, then callers will be unaffected by the change. This is actually a key attribute of a good practice. The read-only vector is also much better than writing custom iterators, because STL objects have a rich interface that includes iterators, access operations, and capacity queries. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, using "const &" should indicate to any C++ programmer: You're really not supposed to modify this. If you're really paranoid, you'll have to clone the vector.